# Can I transfer all of my Keypass details from one machine to another?

Tags: transfer

If I have [Keypass](http://keepass.info/) installed on two separate machines, is it possible to transfer all my passwords and usernames from one machine to the other?

Is there some in-built option or setting which can facilitate this?

Comment: A [quick search](https://www.google.com.kh/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=keepass%20export) reveals many file format options for import/export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keepass databases are stored in files. Depending on how your database is protected (password, key file or both), you could need your key file as well, but you can always open that file on several machines.

In short, there's nothing machine-specific on that file that would disallow opening the file on a different PC (unless also protected with a key file, in that case you'd also need that file to open your Keepass database).

Comment: On 20240106 I attempted to migrate a KeePassXC database (version 2.7.6) between two Ubuntu Mate 22.04 LTS machines, both by copying the Passwords.kdbx found in ~/.config/ and using the "save database as" then "open database" in the Database menu of KeePassXC. Both approaches failed to correctly migrate the 2FA settings, as KeePassXC on the target machine could not generate TOPT codes that would be accepted by github.